# Java Time Zones

Tags: java, timezone

I'm using Java FX form and controller.  It is connected to a MySQL database as well.  I am on a screen to input data, and one of the fields is "start" and "end" times for a specified date. In the database, there is a start timestamp, and end timestamp.

Problem is, this application is set to run in a variety of time zones.  It needs validation.  So, I was thinking - maybe I could populate combo boxes in 1 hour increments for start and end times based on the end-users time zone.

The business is open from 8a-5p EST

So what I was thinking is I could grab the time zone to figure out what 8a is in the end-users time zone, and figure out what 5p is in the end-users time zone, and write code to populate the combo boxes with this time information in one hour increments.  Therefore it would be bypassing the validation.

If I don't do this, I have to populate combo boxes with a very wide time range and validate the time falls within 8a-5p EST.  I am also totally stupid when it comes to understanding the ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime, and how to pass this information around.  A brief explanation would be much appreciated or examples of how I can do this without losing my mind.  When I push or pull data from the database this happens on the fly, but not so much inside the program.  thanks!

Comment: Specify your particular database and JDBC drivers, their versions, and the *exact* data type of your database column.

Answer (score 1):

> when it comes to understanding the ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime, and how to pass this information around.

Date-time handling is surprisingly tricky. Our quotidian intuitive understanding of date-time works *against* us as programmers.

Booking appointments has been handled many times on Stack Overflow, so I will try to be brief. Search to learn more, and see more examples.

The `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` classes each represent a moment, a specific point on the time line. For example, when logging, use `Instant`.

The `LocalDateTime` class does *not* represent a moment. Holding only a date and a time of day, this class lacks the context of a time zone or offset. For example, “noon on the 23rd of January this year” does not tell us if you mean noon in Tokyo Japan or noon in Toledo Ohio US, two very different moments several hours apart.

Booking appointments generally focuses on a particular time-of-day rather than a moment. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for changing the rules of the time zones under their jurisdiction. They do so with little or no forewarning. So we must record an appointment in a database as two columns, the date with time when appointment begins goes in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` , a column of type text keeps the name of the intended time zone, and a third column tracks the duration of the appointment. If the database does not have a type for span-of-time, then use a textual type to store the [ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

You seem to have the additional complication of wanting to provide a user interface that displays the range of possible appointments by the user’s time zone rather than the vendor’s.

So you need to record the appointment in those two columns using the vendor’s zone, but adjust display to the user’s zone. The use’s time zone will be used only for display, not storage.

You said:

> The business is open from 8a-5p EST

```
LocalTime open = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime close = LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 ) ;
```

There is no such time zone as `EST`. Those 2-4 letter abbreviations are non-standard vague indicators of an intended time zone along with whether or not Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect. Never use these pseudo-zones in your work. User real time zone names in format of `Continent/Region`.

```
ZoneId zoneOfBusiness = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

You said:

> 1 hour increments for start and end times

```
List< LocalTime > hoursOfBusiness = new ArrayList<>() ;
LocalTime lt = open ; 
while( lt.isBefore( close ) ) 
{
    hoursOfBusiness.add( lt ) ;
    // Set up next loop.
    lt = lt.plusHours( 1 ) ;
}
```

> [08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00]

To get moments, specify a date. Keep in mind that a date in ambiguous. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Determine moments for each of those hours.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
ArrayList< ZonedDateTime > hoursOfBusinessOnDate = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( LocalTime localTime : hoursOfBusiness )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , localTime , zoneOfBusiness ) ;
    hoursOfBusinessOnDate.add( zdt ) ;
}
```

> [2022-01-23T08:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T09:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T10:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T11:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T12:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T13:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T14:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T15:00-05:00[America/New_York], 2022-01-23T16:00-05:00[America/New_York]]

```
ZoneId zoneOfUser = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ArrayList< ZonedDateTime > hoursOfUserOnDate = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( ZonedDateTime zdtBusiness : hoursOfBusinessOnDate )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdtUser = zdtBusiness.withZoneSameInstant( zoneOfUser ) ;
    hoursOfUserOnDate.add( zdtUser ) ;
}
```

> [2022-01-23T05:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T06:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T07:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T08:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T09:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T10:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T11:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T12:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], 2022-01-23T13:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]]

Present that list to the user, after automatically localizing. Let’s suppose our user is from Québec.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
List< String > choices = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( ZonedDateTime zdt : hoursOfUserOnDate ) 
{
    String choice = zdt.format( f ) ;
    choices.add( choice ) ;
}
```

> choices: [23 janv. 2022 05 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 06 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 07 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 08 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 09 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 10 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 11 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 12 h 00 min 00 s, 23 janv. 2022 13 h 00 min 00 s]

When the user chooses one, convert back to the business zone.

```
ZonedDateTime userChoice = hoursOfUserOnDate.get( 1 ) ; // Get second element, simulating user's choice.
ZonedDateTime userChoiceForBusiness = userChoice.withZoneSameInstant( zoneOfBusiness ) ;
```

> userChoice: 2022-01-23T06:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> userChoiceForBusiness: 2022-01-23T09:00-05:00[America/New_York]

Extract the date and time only, omitting the time zone.

```
LocalDateTime appointmentStart = userChoiceForBusiness.toLocalDateTime() ;
```

> appointmentStart: 2022-01-23T09:00

In database, record the start, the intended time zone, and the duration.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , appointmentStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , zoneOfBusiness.toString() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , Duration.ofHours( 1 ).toString() ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDateTime appointmentStart = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId zoneOfBusiness = ZoneId.of( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
Duration duration = Duration.parse( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
```

When building a schedule, you will need to determine a moment. **Never store this moment**, as it is not really your appointment. It represents the moment of your appointment *as it seems now* given the current set of time zone rules.

```
ZonedDateTime begin = appointmentStart.atZone( zoneOfBusiness ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = begin.plus( duration ) ;
```

> begin: 2022-01-23T09:00-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> end: 2022-01-23T10:00-05:00[America/New_York]

To adjust to UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant beginUtc = begin.toInstant() ;
```

> beginUtc: 2022-01-23T14:00:00Z

See most of that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/eBs2fU).

---

Be sure to keep all the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) data files up-to-date. Your server’s host operating system has one. Your [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) has one. And if your database is sophisticated, such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), you'll find a *tzdata* there too.

Comment: WOW much appreciated thank you!  This gives me a plethora of information that I can use to get started in an easy way to understand.  I am using JDBC version 8.0.25 so the conversions happen on the fly when writing or retrieving from the database, just when I need to check the program information is when I get into some trouble.

Comment: @axk5216 There is no JDBC 8. [JDBC 4.3](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) is the latest.